# What's worse for post-processing blurriness, graininess or softness?

Tags: post-processing, aperture, depth-of-field, blur, iso-noise

**Context**

Using an a6000, I've been learning a lot about photography and how to control the
depth of field (by changing the aperture), blurriness (by changing the shutter speed), and the noise floor/light sensitivity (by changing the ISO). However, when shooting at night, or really in any dark place, it gets harder to get the right, or at least usable exposure.

**Question**

Assuming that I change any of the above three parameters(Aperture, Shutter Speed and ISO), and it won't impact the final image I want, which one of these parameters has the least impact on the final image? Another way to put it, which one of the three parameters is easiest to recover/fix in post-processing or does that depend on the image itself?

I realized that using flash IS an option in some cases, but not in all cases.

Comment: I believe the answer will depend on your subject, and on other factors such as whether you can use a tripod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "universal" answer. Some shots are unrescuably destroyed by even a moderate amount of grain; another ones are easily tuneable in post.
In my practice, ISO usually is the easiest one, then comes the sharpness. 
Remember that each of these "bad" things you can use to tell a story. For example, blur is great for showing motion, eg. silhouettes of dancing people. Turn camera limitations into creative decisions.

Comment: I wanted to say exactly the same thing! Especially about tuning settings to art and vision.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of taste, and the subject, the photo style etc.

But in my opinion, for a "normal" every day point of view. From worst to just bad.

I'm abmivalent on 1 and 2. Becouse the question is which is easier to recover on post pro. In post pro sometimes is easier to sharpen a bit a little out of focus image.

1) Camera shake. Ok you could have a moving fast speed object. But if all the photo is shakey... Use a tripod, or a IS lens, or lower focal lenght. There are too many options to choose for.

2) Out of Focus. If you do not have your main subject in focus this could be just disaster! But a small ammount of out of focus can be "corrected" with some sharpen, and reducing the file size.

3) Iso. Some noise can be lowered using some special filters.

---

When taking the actual photo I would say the order is diferent. **I would prioritize the focus above all**.